# Visual Studio Code doesn't auto update. I need download all file of new version to update it

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have set update Mode is default. If I click the 'Check for Updates...' button, it will change to 'Download Update'. If I check it, all files will download. So, what should I do that the Visual Studio Code could autoupdate?

[image: image of button "Check for Updates..."]

[image: image of button "Download Update (1)"]

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of Codium (1.74.xxx) this does not seem possible. Under the settings in the vanilla application you can only set when it checks for updates:

1. Default - Periodically while using the app using a background checker
2. Start - Only at app start
3. Manual - When you click the check for updates menu item
4. Disabled

Pictured:

[image]

If you still want auto-updates, you would need to create a script that would poll github/a mirror periodically (there may be an RSS feed somewhere), download the zip, and extract to your folder+update your shortcuts. There may be a shortcut/plugin out there that does this.